# FlaskForm cannot submit data

Tags: flask

I'm using Flask-WTF to submit data to a form, but I can't get any data when the form is submitted. This is my LoginForm class:

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username=StringField('Username')
    password=PasswordField('Password')

    def validate(self):

        check_validate = super(LoginForm, self).validate()

        if not check_validate:
            return False
        logging.error('username is %s'%(self.username)
        user=User.query.filter_by(username=self.username.data).first()
        if not user:
            logging.error('username %s: Invalid username or password'%self.username.data)
            self.username.errors.append(
                'Invalid username or password'
            )

            return False

        if not user.checkPassword(self.password.data):
            logging.error('password %s:Invalid username or password'%self.password.data)
            self.username.errors.append(
                'Invalid username or password'
            )

            return False

        return True
```

And here is my form:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% from 'base.html' import input %}
{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    <form method='POST' action="{{ url_for('main.login')}}">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        {{ input(form.username, 'Username') }}
        {{ input(form.password, 'Password') }}
        <input class='btn-primary' type='submit' value='Login'>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

the input file is a jinaja macro containing

```
{% macro input(name, label, value='', type='text') %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for='{{ name }}'>{{ label }}</label>
        <input type='{{ type }}' name='{{ name }}' value='{{ value | escape }}' class='form-control'>
    </div>

{% endmacro %}
```

so when I input some data in this form and submit, I always saw

> ERROR:root:username is 
>   <input id="username" name="username" type="text" value="">

It seems like no data has been pass to LoginForm

What should I do?

```
@main_blueprint.route('/login', methods=('GET','POST'))
def login():
    form = LoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash("Your have been logged in.", category="success")
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        return render_template(
            'user.html',
            user=user
        )
    return render_template('login.html', form = form)

main_blueprint = Blueprint(
    'main',
    __name__,
    template_folder='../templates/main'
)
```

new:
I tried to submit my form by 'GET' method, and I found my username and password was passed, but I still can't get them in my LoginForm

> ```
> 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2018 01:05:18] "GET /login?csrf_token=...input+ 
> id%3D%22username%22+
> name%3D%22username%22+
> type%3D%22text%22+
> value%3D%22%22%3E=mer&%3C
> input+
> id%3D%22password%22+
> name%3D%22password%22+
> type%3D%22password%22+
> value%3D%22%22%3E=dly1234&
> submit=Login+In HTTP/1.1" 200 -
> ```

'mer' and 'dly1234' is username and pwd I inputted.

Comment: Did you check this tutorial - https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms? I guess you are missing route, which accepts POST requests (but I'm not sure in it)...

Comment: @kosist No, I haven't read that tutorial, and I routed the URL in main_blueprint, was supplemented in my question.

Comment: One more idea - don't you need to include `{{ form.submit() }}` into html template?

Comment: I've just tried this method, but it doesn't seem to work TOT, I thought Mega use `form.submit()` just because he defined the SubmitField in form, but so many tutorial user HTML word like `<input type=submit>` is not wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was resolved, I read the login page's HTML code and found in my latest version the `input` in form is:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for='<input id="username" name="username" type="text" value="">'>Username</label>
    <input type='text' name='<input id="username" name="username" type="text" value="">' value='' class='form-control'>
</div>
```

I noticed the name in this is strange, So I back to change my jinja:

before:

```
{{ input(form.username, 'Username') }}
```

now:

```
 {{ input('username', 'Username') }}
```

End of the question.

And thanks @kosist, the Mega's tutorial gives me so many helpful, his implement method inspired me to compare the difference between our final HTML code.